# Can a text file be put among other resources in a Java project?

Tags: java, project

I have been working on several natural language processing projects, with Java as my choice of programming language. I find that there are some plain text files (e.g. a file with the list of stop-words) which I use repeatedly. Since I often find myself working from different locations and different machines, I was wondering if these text files can be put in the `lib` folder, along with all the other resources (e.g. external .jar files).

I have never seen .txt files being placed in the `lib` folder, so I would like to ask two things:

1. Will placing a .txt file in `lib` work, or will it lead to some unintended disaster?
2. What is the conventional way of placing/using such resources?

Comment: You could just try it.

Comment: Also what is the difference to a computer between a file with a `txt` extension and a file with a `random123` extension?

Comment: I was just thinking the same ... I guess I want to follow a conventional design/structure rather than do something off the top of my head.

Comment: Don't put it in the lib folder. Usually you should have a resources folder that gets copied to the classes dir so you file ends up in the class path. Of course you could put it in a sub folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a conventional Maven layout for your source tree, place your stop words in *src/main/resources*. You are welcome to place your stop words in whatever folder structure that is intuitive for you and your team--or none at all (right at the top level).

That's all you need to worry about as Maven or Gradle will package things in the war file as they should be. You then fetch this resource in code with `getResourceAsStream` called with a path relative to the *resources* folder in your source tree.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `/lib/` contents, including the text file, are put on the classpath, you can safely obtain text resources via `SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt")`.

`/` indicates absolute path. Otherwise, the path is relative to the package of `SomeClass` (which, in turn, would be relative to `lib`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put whatever file in your jar, in any folder, so for read this file you use this:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folder/textfile.txt"))
```

Comment: `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` are designed to only target resources on the classpath. The author does not imply that `lib` is a package that will be included in the application's JAR.

Comment: Those methods delegate to the ClassLoader (So it could be in the classpath but depends of the class loader) to try to get the resource, I don't assume the lib is a package I only say how to load the file.

Comment: However, you have to admit that writing a `ClassLoader` just to allow such access to external resources is far from optimal :)